# how to hide element using name and id together (How to hide)

Tags: javascript

I want to hide span tag containing "Prasad" using only java script.
u can see there is div tag also having same id which i don't want to hide at all.

```
<body onload="onLoad();">
    <div id="123">div</div>
    <li id="test">
        <span id="123" class="alert" >Prasad</span>
    </li>
    <li id="test">
        <span  id="456" class="alert" >Mphasis</span>
    </li>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad()
{
    var x= document.getElementById("123").getElementsByClassName("alert");
    x.style.display="none"; --->> getting error here as undefine
}
</script>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique!

Comment: @j08691 is correct (about `id="test"`). Also, try `document.getElementById("123").style.display="none"; `.

Comment: like above said ids should be unique use classes instead and use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector .

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, so you need to use `x[0]`

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique. Instead you should use `class` and check if element contains `class` alert or not by using [element.classList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) like this

```js
function onLoad() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("123")
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].classList.contains("alert")) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad();">
  <div class="123">div</div>
  <li class="test">
    <span class="123 alert">Prasad</span>
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    <span id="456" class="alert">Mphasis</span>
  </li>
</body>
```

**P.S** `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of Object

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your current `id="test"` into `class="test"`. As mentioned by other users, ids should be unique.

This will then let you add an `id` to the `<li>` element you want to hide.
So your code will look like so:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
  <div class="123">div</div>
  <li class="test" id="prasad">
    <span class="123 alert">Prasad</span>
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    <span id="456" class="alert">Mphasis</span>
  </li>
</body>
```

You can then hide the 'Prasad' element with jQuery like so:

`$('#prasad').css({display:"none"});`

This would be done inside the `onLoad()` function